# Android Spinner: Application cannot compile when using setVisibility on spinner

Tags: android, spinner, visibility

I've been having issues when trying to setVisibility to a spinner. Basically there are two spinners. The first spinner has the options yes and no. When the program starts the default option will be yes and the second spinner should be invisible. When the user selects no on the first spinner then the second spinner becomes visible. When I comment out the code for visibility the program compiles on the emulator.

I don't know why the app keeps crashing as soon as i try to make the spinner visible or invisible. Any help would be much appreciated. I thank you in advance for your time and effort.

This is my main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView android:text="@string/CO" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/co" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/attendance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/Attendance"
        android:prompt="@string/present" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/Status"
        android:prompt="@string/status" />



</LinearLayout>
```

This is strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Parade State Gen</string>

<string name="CO">CO</string>
<string name="present">Present?</string>
<string name="status">Status</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>



<string-array name="Attendance">
    <item>Yes</item>
    <item>No</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="Status">
    <item>LL</item>
    <item>OL</item>
    <item>PCL</item>
    <item>CCL</item>
    <item>O/S</item>
    <item>CNB</item>
    <item>TNB</item>
    <item>MC</item>
    <item>RSO</item>
    <item>RS</item>
    <item>OC</item>
    <item>AS</item>
    <item>AO</item>
</string-array>
```

This is the main class

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Spinner attendance, status;
private Button btnSubmit;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addItemsOnAttendance();

    //addListenerOnButton();


}

public void addItemsOnAttendance() {
    attendance = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.attendance);
    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.Attendance, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    attendance.setAdapter(adapter);

    attendance.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            String myData = attendance.getSelectedItem().toString();
            int pos = adapter.getPosition(myData);
            if (pos == 1) {

                status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), myData + " already in Spinner", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
            } else {

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

            // your code here
        }

    });


}
    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection () {
        status = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.status);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.Status, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        status.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

Comment: Where is your code for ``addListenerOnButton()`` ?

Comment: it doesn't exist. i have to delete it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize spinner variable after call `setVisiblity`, that's why you receiving NullPointerException. It should be something like that:

```
addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Btw, read something about [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) - it impossible to do android apps without it.

Comment: That did it! Thank you for your help and I'll read up on logcat as well.